# Generate data flow graph for ETL process

Tags: visualization, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, graphviz, dfd

I would like to generate something like a data flow diagram for an ETL process.

What I want to achieve is to have (the minimal example) two tables - source and destination - both tables with their attributes and between them a process, that transforms data from the first to the second table. Within this process I want to display the relationship to input fields, output fields and description of the formula/expression.

Of course, then for real world scenario I need multiple source tables for one deatination and the whole chain, where the data flows from input table to the final destination one through multiple tables.

I tried to generate something in graphviz, but if it is only a bit more complicated than completely simple, I can't force it to keep the expected layout and it's just a mess.

Here is some mspaint mockup for what layout I am after. But there is more tables (~10), around the same amount of processes, but hundreds of attributes and derivation functions.
[image: Mockup]

Comment: please post your Graphviz code & a description of what is wrong or what you really want.

Comment: @sroush it would be not much helpful to share the actual code as this is really huge and it honestly does not work at all. I added a mock drawing to the question and currently I am not even close to this. I can force Graphviz to stack couple attributes on above another (using the groups and invisible edge hack), it may work for some time, but when I add some amount of complexity, it breaks anyway. If you can provide some template setup how to force it to keep the layout, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very fiddly, but also very scriptable.  See the Graphviz documentation as needed, esp. https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html

```
digraph ETL {
  rankdir=LR
    
  subgraph clusterA {
    graph [label="Table A"]
    // unfortunately, if we let each attribute have its own node, they end up ordered last-to-first
    // not interested in fighting this, so put them all in a table that looks like individual nodes
    //
    //  see below for fix to the above mentioned last-to-first bug
    //  I am to lazy to apply it to the three Tables
    //
    node [width=2.5]
    TA [shape=none label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="4">
        <tr><td width="130" port="A1">Attribute 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="invis"></td></tr>
        <tr><td port="A2">Attribute 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="invis"></td></tr>
        <tr><td port="A3">Attribute 3</td></tr>
        </table>>]
  }

  subgraph clusterP {
    graph [label="Process P"]
    node [shape=none]

    subgraph clusterP1 {
      graph [label="Attribute 1 Derivation"]
      {rank=same
      F1 [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" port="f1" width="160" align="text" balign="left">Function 1<BR align="right"/>IF<BR align="left"/>blah blah<BR align="left"/>more<BR/>blah blah<BR/>and more<BR/>blah blah<BR/>no more</td>
          <td port="sa1">Source 1</td>
      </tr>
          <tr>  <td port="sa2">Source 2</td> </tr>
          <tr>  <td port="sa3">Source 3</td> </tr>
          </table>>]
      F2 [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" port="f1" width="160" align="text" balign="left">Function 2<BR align="right"/>IF<BR align="left"/>blah blah<BR align="left"/>more<BR/>blah blah<BR/>and more<BR/>blah blah<BR/>no more</td>
          <td port="sa1">Source 1</td>
      </tr>
          <tr>  <td port="sa2">Source 2</td> </tr>
          <tr>  <td port="sa3">Source 3</td> </tr>
          </table>>]
      }
    F2->F1  [style=invis] // yes, this is backwards & stupid, but it gets the nodes inthe correct order
    }

  }

 subgraph clusterB {
    graph [label="Table B"]
    TB [shape=none label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="4">
        <tr><td port="A1">Attribute 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="invis"></td></tr>
        <tr><td port="A2">Attribute 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="invis"></td></tr>
        <tr><td port="A3">Attribute 3</td></tr>
        </table>>]
  }
 subgraph clusterC {
    graph [label="Table C"]
    TC [shape=none label=<
        <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="4">
        <tr><td port="A1">Attribute 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="invis"></td></tr>
        <tr><td port="A2">Attribute 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="invis"></td></tr>
        <tr><td port="A3">Attribute 3</td></tr>
        </table>>]
  }

  TA:A1 ->  F1:f1
  F1:sa1 -> TB:A1
  F1:sa2 -> TB:A2
  F1:sa3 -> TC:A1

}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks really promissing! Thanks a lot for that, I will try that out with larger amount of components.